# Windows Path - no Program Files (x86)

Tags: windows, cmd

[image]

When I follow the tutorials on how to change paths in Windows 10, everyone is telling me to go into Advanced Settings, Environment Variables, locate Path, and change the following text after `C:\Program Files (x86):` . However, when I click edit, I am presented with a list of `%SystemRoot%` paths, and Program Files is nowhere to be found. What is the issue here?

Thanks!

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86) isn't a standard part of the path. Perhaps you should state a problem.

Comment: I need to be able to use `g++` in my command line in order to compile C++ programs. However, the tutorials on Youtube are of no help because my paths are different theirs. And anytime I try to add my compiler path to the `Path` label in Advanced Settings, there is still no difference. It always tells me `'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Type in a command prompt - `setx path "%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows"` Alter to  suit your program.

Comment: What does that command do?

Comment: Add debugging tools for windows folder to the path. Note I've edited it to include any existing path (none by default on windows).

Comment: Ok, it said that specified value was saved, but g++ still doesn't work

Comment: You need to restart the command prompt. Type `path` to check your changes. I might point out you haven't provided any details such as the directory you want to add.

Comment: ...all I had to do was restart the command prompt haha. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you do everything correct except you do not have to change any text. Just append any path you wish at the end of `PATH` variable for example I appended my python path like this `;C:\Python27`.

[image]

In your case just add `;C:\Program Files (x86)\whatever you want` at the end of `PATH`

Comment: It's weird though. When I select `Path` and click `Edit...` , it opens the window that is shown in the picture above. Whereas in your photo, it says `Variable Name` and `Variable Value`, mine does not. It opens that list with a bunch of different `%SystemRoot%` paths.

Comment: Just create `new` path with value 'C:\Program Files (x86)\whatever you want' or press `browse` and navigate manually whatever you want. Should work.

Comment: I added `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW` into a new entry, but when I still type `'g++` into the command line, it says `g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                                                             operable program or batch file.`

Comment: That makes sense because `g++` is not in that directory, it is in `bin`. So instead add `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin`